# SVN Branch Reintegration

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I am trying to figure out what is best practice for reintegrating two separate branches (one branch off trunk,second branch off of branch one) back into trunk.

These branches are essentially feature branches that need to be moved into trunk since they have reached production.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Trunk on Rev: 400

B1 Created on Rev:50 From Trunk, Current Rev: 150

B2 Created on Rev:100 From B1, Current Rev:200

---

Option One: Merge T -> B1, Merge B1 -> B2, Merge B2 -> T, Delete B1 & B2

Option Two: Merge B1 -> B2, Merge B2 -> B1, Merge B1 -> T, Delete B1 & B2

Option Other: ??

---

[image: Image Describing Problem]

Comment: Sync b1 with trunk, sync b2 with b1, merge b2 to trunk. Make sure to use up-to-date SVN 1.9 client and read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature & http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync & http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate

Comment: @bahrep - "sync b2 with b1" is Bad and Wrong Idea *if* they represent **independent** features

Comment: I assumed that they are depend on each other

Comment: In this case B2 modifies functionality added in B1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very important to merge with respective ancestor. So merge B1 with B2 then merge B1 to Trunk. This is my recommendation.